# Maven: excluding java files in compilation

Tags: maven

I have a folder of java sources which I wish to exclude from the compilation.

My folder is under `qa/apitests/src/main/java/api/test/omi`.

I added the following entry in the `pom.xml` under `qa/bamtests` but it didn't help. Is there an entry in addition I need to make?

```
       <build>
         <resources>
           <resource>
             <directory>src/main/java</directory>
             <includes>
               <include>**/*.properties</include>
               <include>**/*.xml</include>
               <include>**/*.xsd</include>
               <include>**/*.csv</include>
             </includes>
             <excludes>
               <exclude>src/main/java/api/test/omi</exclude>
             </excludes>
           </resource>
        </build>
```

Comment: Location for properties is `src/main/resources` for test properties `src/test/resources`.

Comment: How does your project in `qa/bamtests` even find the sources in `qa/apitests`?

Comment: what about using the same pattern for excludes: <exclude>**/test/omi/**</exclude>

Comment: a bit off topic: your way to organize resources is just a mess.  You should put it in src/main/resources (or create other directories under src/main/ ) to organize your different kind of resources

Comment: Read [Stefan's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19713000/239408)  about the need to remove `src/main/java/` from the path!

Answer (score 79, accepted):

Use the [Maven Compiler Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/).

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/api/test/omi/*.java</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: What does the two leading `*` stand for ?

Comment: The `**` mean 'any directories'.

Comment: This answer didn't work for me. Look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/19713000/358013

Comment: For me it did not work either, I had to remove `src/main/java` part ... Looks like a relative path issue. Can someone please explain in detail?

Comment: @SoumyaKanti, not 100% sure, but the maven compiler plugin handles java sources. It normally expects them to reside in src/main/java (according to the archetype structure), and thus is limited to operate within that directory sub-tree. The behavior might have been different for older versions of the plugin though.

Comment: To exclude tests, see @michal-kordas 's answer on http://stackoverflow.com/a/32531306/517134 it worked for me

Comment: what is the difference between this exclude and the exclude that can be used in the build tag?

Comment: It worth saying, compiler will ignore these excludes if excluded java file referenced (for example, in imports) from another (non-excluded) file

Answer (score 49):

Adding an exclude as the other answers suggested worked for me, except the path shouldn't include "src/main/java":

```
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
      <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
      <configuration>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>com/filosync/store/StoreMain.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: remove src/main/ is so true!

Answer (score 39):

For anyone needing to exclude **test sources** `<exclude>` tag will not work. You need to use `<testExclude>` instead:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3</version>
    <configuration>
      <testExcludes>
        <testExclude>**/PrefixToExclude*</testExclude>
      </testExcludes>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Comment: Documented here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/testCompile-mojo.html

Answer (score 3):

The top voted answer works fine but it doesn't allow forcing the exclusion when the excluded class/classes is/are being used by not-excluded ones.

Workaround using `maven-antrun-plugin`:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <tasks>
            <delete dir="target/classes/folder/to/exclude"/>
        </tasks>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to exclude the java sources from compiling, then mention them in the [Maven Compiler Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/) definition

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2</version>
        <configuration>
            <excludes>
              <exclude>src/main/java/api/test/omi/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

The resources plugin only defines what all resources to bundle in your final artifact.