# How to ignore some java file when maven install

Tags: maven, exec-maven-plugin

I am new to maven.Now in my maven project,there are some java files like helloworldMock.java(they all end with 'Mock.java') I don't when to use them when I run `mvn install`some time.
How I can do?

Comment: This sounds like the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/223467). What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to ignore some file when I run `mvn install`，and this file are end with  'Mock.java'. For example , HelloworldMock.java . I don't want to build this class Helloworld.

Comment: That's already the implementation details of a solution. **Why** would you want to do this? What's the endgame?

Comment: what's mean 'That's already the implementation details of a solution'?

Comment: I want to do this because sometimes I want to use this class but sometimes I don't want to use them.

Comment: Agree with Mureinik why would you want to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maven: excluding java files in compilation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920920/maven-excluding-java-files-in-compilation)