# how can I tell intellj not to compile certain files?

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-14

I got a bunch of java files that I don't want to be compiled as part of the module. Is there a way to tell intellij to ignore them?

Comment: If you are using Maven, you can use the compiler plugin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920920/maven-excluding-java-files-in-compilation

Comment: I'd rather ask myself: why do I add Java source files in the directory supposed to contain all Java source files that must be compiled if I don't want them to be compiled? Why don't you just delete those files? Or put them somewhere else? What are these source files for?