# How to exclude some *.java files from the Maven build?

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin

I expect to find help here regarding the problem of excluding some files from the Maven build.

The essence of the problem I have a package in my Java application that needs to be almost completely excluded (except for a couple of classes) from the project for a certain period of time. Here is its structure.

```
$ tree ./ -d
./
├── controller
│   └── dto
│       ├── rq
│       │   └── dss
│       └── rs
├── dao
│   └── impl
├── jobs
├── model
└── service
    ├── dto
    │   └── rq
    │       └── clientprofile
    └── impl
```

I tried the following solutions and none of them worked:

```
1. 

 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp-${app.face}</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webappf</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>controller/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>dao/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>jobs/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>model/**</exclude>
                                <exclude>service/dto/**</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

2.


 <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <webResources>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp-${app.face}</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp</directory>
                            <filtering>false</filtering>
                        </resource>
                        <resource>
                            <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webappf</directory>
                            <filtering>true</filtering>
                        </resource>
                    </webResources>
                    <packagingExcludes>
                        WEB-INF/classes/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/controller/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/dao/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/jobs/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/model/**,
                        WEB-INF/classes/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/service/dto/**
                    </packagingExcludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>


3.  


  <!--Parent pom.xml-->    
  <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.1</version>
                    <configuration>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <excludes>
                            <exclude>src/main/java/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/controller/**/*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>src/main/java/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/dao/**/*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>src/main/java/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/jobs/**/*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>src/main/java/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/model/**/*.java</exclude>
                            <exclude>src/main/java/com/<NDA>/<NDA>/server/<NDA>/service/dto/rq/**/*.java</exclude>
                        </excludes>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>



  <!--Child pom.xml-->
  <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                        <configuration combine.self="override">
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe duplicate question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920920/maven-excluding-java-files-in-compilation/32531306

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven: excluding java files in compilation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920920/maven-excluding-java-files-in-compilation)

Comment: Why specifically does it need to be "excluded"? What specifically does "excluded" mean?

Comment: @AndreaGirardi, Karthikeyan Vaithilingam I have tried all options except the plugin maven-antrun-plugin, but I still see these files in my war.

Comment: @chrylis-cautiouslyoptimistic- This means that at least these files should not be in war, and better not even compiled. I need to remove some of the logic for now, which is not to bring in the release of migrations that may be changed in the future.

Comment: If you don't want them now, then why not *remove the files*? Just delete them. If you need them again later on, you can still find them in your history (you are using a VCS, right?)

Comment: In general if you don't want to compile classes (as already suggest) just remove them? The question is why are they part of the project if not being compiled? Apart from that you are using extremely old versions of plugins and also the given configuration is bad practice if not even wrong...This looks: `${basedir}/src/main/webapp-${app.face}` really strange to be honest?

Answer (score -1):

As was already said in the comments.

If you don't want files in the build, just delete them.

If you need them later, recover them from your git or svn.