# How to prevent scala-maven-plugin from compiling Java sources?

Tags: java, scala, maven, scala-maven-plugin

There is a mixed (Java + Scala) Maven project.
Only a small part is written in Scala and it does not depend on Java code.
Java code depends on compilation results of the Scala part.

I'm looking for a way to compile in two steps:

1. compile only Scala code (using `scala-maven-plugin`)
2. compile only Java code (using `maven-compiler-plugin`)

By default `scala-maven-plugin` compiles everything in `src/main/java, src/main/scala`
and it would be great to have an option to alter this behaviour.

Tried to search in documentation, but did not manage to find any mentions of how to exclude sources from compilation.

**How to configure `scala-maven-plugin` so it would compile only Scala source code?**

Comment: Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17920920/maven-excluding-java-files-in-compilation (example using the maven compiler plugin) and here: https://davidb.github.io/scala-maven-plugin/compile-mojo.html (configuration options of the scala maven plugin). You might also want to look into Maven profiles if you want to enable/disable plugins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this snippet](https://github.com/davidB/scala-maven-plugin/blob/3227814b127066ae4e9b13843eabe4db7aefc2ff/src/it/includesExcludes/pom.xml#L33-L41) in an integration test:

```xml
<configuration>
    <includes>
        <include>**/*.scala</include>
        <include>**/TestClass.java</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
        <exclude>bad.scala</exclude>
    </excludes>
</configuration>
```

It appears that you can probably use the `<excludes>` tag inside `<configuration>` to exclude `src/main/java/**/*.java`.

Comment: Just tested on a small example project and this does indeed prevent the Scala compiler from compiling your Java code (my compilation suddenly fails because I had a dependency from my Scala code to my Java code). You have to fiddle a bit more to make sure that the necessary classfiles are available depending on whether you have Scala code depending on Java code (or the other way around). How to do this is beyond my expertise in Maven.

Comment: works like a charm. Accidentally there is also one *.java class in my project which Scala code depends on. So I just included it: `<include>**/MyClass.java</include><include>**/*.scala</include>`.