# How to get java to ignore an error while running?

Tags: java, eclipse, compiler-errors

My java program runs perfectly in eclipse (just outputting the error) but when I try and export it and run it as a jar it stops because of the error. How do I get java to ignore the error?

Here is the error I encountered:

```
ERROR StatusLogger Unable to locate a logging implementation, using SimpleLogger

FATAL Launcher Unhandled exception in thread Thread[main,5,main] java.lang.refle
ct.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.jarinjarloader.JarRsrcLoader.main(JarRsrcLoa
der.java:58)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.ui.TexturedPanel.<init>(TexturedPanel.java:23)

    at net.minecraft.launcher.ui.LauncherPanel.<init>(LauncherPanel.java:36)

    at net.minecraft.launcher.SwingUserInterface.initializeFrame(SwingUserIn
terface.java:108)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Launcher.<init>(Launcher.java:91)
    at net.minecraft.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:56)
    ... 5 more
```

Comment: try{}catch(Exception){}, but be aware, error are meaningful

Comment: see this... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7590275/ignoring-compilation-errors-java.. might be helpful

Comment: Please show the error message.

Comment: @Danielson I did not make the class with the error and it is already compiled so I cannot easily edit it

Comment: Then some more information... Does something gets thrown? How do you call it?

Comment: IllegalArgumentException: input == null! <- looks like you need to add an uri to an image

Answer (score 1):

Use a try catch method try{    } catch(Exception)

this is a helpful link too https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/try.html